# Adding to std::shared_ptr of vector causes segfault

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, shared-ptr

I have this sample program. All I'm trying to do is to share an instance of vector among the objects contained in the vector itself so that they can manipulate (add other objects, remove themselves) from the container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class SimpleClass {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<SimpleClass>> objects;

public:
  SimpleClass (std::shared_ptr<std::vector<SimpleClass>> _objects): objects { _objects } {}

  void grow () {
    std::cout << "growing" << std::endl;
    for (int i { 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
      std::cout << "about to add a new object" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "current simple_objects size: " << objects->size() << std::endl;
      objects->push_back(SimpleClass(objects));
      std::cout << "added a new object" << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

int main () {
  auto simple_objects = std::make_shared<std::vector<SimpleClass>>();

  for (int i { 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
    simple_objects->push_back(SimpleClass { simple_objects });
  }

  std::cout << "simple_objects size: " << simple_objects->size() << std::endl;

  for (auto &obj: *simple_objects) {
    obj.grow();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After some iterations, the program exists with a `Segmentation Fault 11`:

```
simple_objects size: 10
growing
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 10
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 11
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 12
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 13
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 14
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 15
added a new object
about to add a new object
current simple_objects size: 16
added a new object
about to add a new object
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The program can be tested here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/rJHSik8Hf

What causes the Segmentation Fault and how to prevent it?

Comment: You have cycles. You are adding the object to itself. Beware, that is potentially a dangerous practice. Maybe when adding and the vector gets resized and memory reallocated something weird could happen. BTW, make your constructor `explicit`.

Comment: Your answer is below (@Sorin's). Make sure you resize enough spaces for the elements (.resize()) before calling grow on the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you reallocate (copy/move) the class while you are still using it.

I'm guessing the vector allocated 16 slots. Now you want to add item 17. This mean the vector needs to allocate a larger array and copy/move the existing items.

That works, but consider the current item (this). It was in the old array. It was moved/copied and the old array was destroyed. So this now points to memory you've just deallocated and you get segfault (lucky).

What you probably want is that resizing the vector doesn't change the items. You can wrap the items in std::unique_ptr and it will work just fine.

Other alternatives are to fix the size of the array so no resizing occurs, or not to modify the array from an object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a local copy of the `shared_ptr` on the stack should solve the problem. (Just the ptr, not the entire vector)

```
void grow () {
    auto localObjects = objects;
    std::cout << "growing" << std::endl;
    for (int i { 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
      std::cout << "about to add a new object" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "current simple_objects size: " << localObjects->size() << std::endl;
      localObjects->push_back(SimpleClass(objects));
      std::cout << "added a new object" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You should also create a copy when iterating as you are modifying the vector when iterating. 
Your code is running without seg fault now. https://onlinegdb.com/H1lNlcgOSG

```
auto localCopy = *simple_objects;
for (auto &obj: localCopy) {
  obj.grow();
}
```